# Delphi: Memory Leak Warning Message

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-2006

I am in the process of creating a small application in Delphi 2006. In one of the classes there is a property of another class. In my onCreate event, I instantiated the objects and also destroy them in the onDestroy event. When I close the application, I get a memory leak warning. I honestly cannot identity the memory leak. Here is the code that I am using, your help will be greatly appreciated.

I can't post an image of the error message, but here is a description.

```
An unexpected memory leak has occurred. The unexpected small block leaks are:
21 - 28 bytes: TPermanentAddress x 1
```

Here is the class:

```
unit uUser;

interface

uses
  classes,SysUtils,Dialogs;


type
TAddress = class
private
 FStreetAddress : string;
 FCity          : string ;
 FState         : string;
 FZipCode       : string;

 procedure setStreetAddress(const Value : string);
 procedure setCity(const Value : string);
 procedure setState(const Value : string);
 procedure setZipCode(const Value : string);

 protected

 public
 property StreetAddress : string read FStreetAddress write setStreetAddress;
 property City : string read FCity write setCity;
 property State : string read FState write setState;
 property ZipCode : string read FZipCode write setZipCode;


end;

type
  TPermanentAdddress = class (TAddress)
  private
  FStartDate     : string;
  FEndDate       : string;

  procedure setStartDate(const Value : string);
  procedure setEndDate(const Value : string);

  protected

  public

  property StartDate : string read FStartDate write setStartDate;
  property EndDate   : string read FEndDate write setEndDate ;
  end;


type
TUser = class(TObject)
  private
  FFirstName : string;
  FAddress : TPermanentAdddress;
  procedure setFirstName(const Value : string);
  procedure setAddress(const Value : TPermanentAdddress);

  protected

  public
  constructor Create(); reintroduce; overload;
  destructor Destroy();  override;
   property FirstName : string read FFirstName write setFirstName;
   property Address : TPermanentAdddress read FAddress write setAddress;

end;

implementation

procedure TAddress.setStreetAddress(const Value : string);
begin
  FStreetAddress := value;
end;

 procedure TAddress.setCity(const Value : string);
 begin
   FCity := Value;
 end;
 procedure TAddress.setState(const Value : string);
 begin
   FState := Value;
 end;
 procedure TAddress.setZipCode(const Value : string);
 begin
   FZipCode := Value;
 end;

 //Permanent Address
  procedure TPermanentAdddress.setStartDate(const Value : string);
  begin
    FStartDate := value;
  end;
  procedure TPermanentAdddress.setEndDate(const Value : string);
  begin
    FEndDate := Value;
  end;

  //tvxpatient
  procedure TUser.setFirstName(const Value : string);
  begin
    FFirstName := Value;
  end;
  procedure TUser.setAddress(const Value : TPermanentAdddress);
  begin
    FAddress := Value;
  end;

  constructor TUser.Create();
  begin
   FAddress := TPermanentAdddress.Create;
  end;

  destructor TUser.Destroy();
  begin
  //FAddress.Free;
  end;

end.
```

Here is the Form:

```
unit Home;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, uUser, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
protected

  public
    { Public declarations }
  aUser : TUser;

  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
addr : TPermanentAdddress;
begin
  aUser := TUser.Create;
  aUser.Address := TPermanentAdddress.Create;
  aUser.FirstName := 'test';
  aUser.Address.StartDate := '03/10/2015';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 aUser.Address.Free; // I am destroying it here, so I thought.
 aUser.Free;
end;

end.
```

In the project, I turned on ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown.

```
program Testing;

uses
  Forms,
  Home in 'Home.pas' {Form1},
  uUser in 'uUser.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
destructor TUser.Destroy();
begin
  //FAddress.Free;
end;
```

Here you fail to destroy `FAddress`. Hence the memory leak.

Your should also call the inherited destructor. It should look like this:

```
destructor TUser.Destroy;
begin
  FAddress.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

On top of this, you are wrong to create `Address` twice. Instead of:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  addr : TPermanentAdddress;
begin
  aUser := TUser.Create;
  aUser.Address := TPermanentAdddress.Create;
  aUser.FirstName := 'test';
  aUser.Address.StartDate := '03/10/2015';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 aUser.Address.Free; // I am destroying it here, so I thought.
 aUser.Free;
end;
```

You need:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  aUser := TUser.Create;
  aUser.FirstName := 'test';
  aUser.Address.StartDate := '03/10/2015';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  aUser.Free;
end;
```

Personally I would use the constructor/destructor of `TForm1` rather than `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` to managed owned objects.

Comment: Strictly speaking, uncommenting the line wouldn't fix the leak since FAddress has been overwritten. Picky... :) Perhaps the memory manager warned of a double free and poster fixed it by commenting the correct code...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, that's probably how the user ended up with the correct code commented out.

Comment: I removed the comment to free FAddress. In addition, I added a constructor and destructor to TForm1, but they are not being called. For example, I added a button and a label; the object is null when I click on the button to update the text in the label. I modify the original post to include the latest changes.

Comment: I made the changes that @David Heffernan suggested. I am no longer getting the memory leak error when I close the form.